# Admob Ads are not shown after downloading from PlayStore

Tags: android, kotlin, admob

My AdMob Ads aren't shown on debug build or after downloading it from PlayStore. Ads are shown perfectly on release build when installed from phone storage. In debug build Ads are shown after adding test device id [shown with a label "Test Ads"] otherwise there are no Ads on debug build with live Ads id.

My App Code:

```
private fun initAds() {
        adRequest = AdRequest.Builder()
//            .addTestDevice("0F599D3CA98C66B708C04713B88C384E")
//            .addTestDevice("49C82A512ED4AFA9D0E3C84BA9A1AEB1")
//            .addTestDevice("25902B4BC782D9DE7CBEB82B8027B726")
            .build()

        val mAdView = binding.adView
        adView.visibility = View.GONE
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest)

        mInterstitialAd = InterstitialAd(this)
        mInterstitialAd.adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx"
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)


        mAdView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded()
                adView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }


        }

        mInterstitialAd.adListener = object : AdListener() {
            override fun onAdClosed() {
                super.onAdClosed()
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest)
            }
            override fun onAdFailed(p0: Int) {
                super.onAdFailed(p0: Int)
                Log.i("Ads", "Ad Failed: "+p0)
            }
        }
    }
```

Some Logs from Logcat

```
2018-12-15 13:42:52.840 32148-32148/com.insightapps.textrepeater.remover I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0F599D3CA98C66B708C04713B88C384E") to get test ads on this device.
2018-12-15 13:42:52.885 32148-32148/com.insightapps.textrepeater.remover I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0F599D3CA98C66B708C04713B88C384E") to get test ads on this device.
2018-12-15 13:42:52.925 32148-32555/com.insightapps.textrepeater.remover W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
2018-12-15 13:42:53.523 28731-32337/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14799021.14300000.1
2018-12-15 13:42:53.544 28731-32595/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v14799021.14300000.1
2018-12-15 13:43:04.150 32148-32148/com.insightapps.textrepeater.remover I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
2018-12-15 13:43:04.851 32148-32148/com.insightapps.textrepeater.remover I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Im Using SDK Version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'
```

Its been 2 days since Im having this issue. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, for no particular reason the AdMob stopped working

Comment: Once  had the same issue. Irony is that if your earning is below $25 per week, you can't even contact AdmoB support. My ads showed up after a month then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ads just showed up after 4 days. I suppose its a change in Google Admob policy

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what you want. Why are not the test ads enough?

Comment: Live build requires live ad unit Ids. Test Ads are just for testing purposes. My live Ids arent shown when app is downloaded from playstore

Answer (score 0):

update your gradle file classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'